# Selecting a value into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm playing around with t-sql and would like to be able to select into some variable.

Currently I just want to get a count(*) for every table in the database and print this.

When I try the following:

> EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+ @table_name)

This gives the counts for all rows, now, I'd like to store the COUNT(*) into a variable. To achieve this i've declared. I've tried a few different approaches, amongst others this one:

> EXEC('SELECT ' + @row_count +' = COUNT(*) FROM '+ @table_name)

Which yields an error (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '='.).

Any idea how to correctly express this?

Comment: Why are you building the query dynamically? SELECT @row_count = COUNT(1) FROM YourTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more efficient way to get the number of rows in a table, by looking at the database metadata.  Here is an alternative solution:

```
declare @NumRows int;
select @NumRows = sum(rows)
from <database>.sys.partitions P join
     <database>.sys.tables T
      on T.[object_id] = P.[object_id]
where index_id IN (0,1) AND T.[type] = 'U' and t.name = '<table>'
```

Comment: I tried looking into sys.tables, didn't know of sys.partitions yet. Thanks!

Comment: @fuaaark One minor drawback: as the documentation notes, the sys.partitions.rows value is "approximate" so it may or may not be suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `sp_executesql`.

Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide output variable from a query and specify that it is for output:

```
declare @table_name nvarchar(100)
declare @row_count int
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @table_name = 'YOUR TABLE NAME'

set @sql = N'SELECT @row_count = COUNT(*) FROM '+ @table_name
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@row_count int output', @row_count = @row_count output
print @row_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably do like this:

```
declare @rowcount int  
declare @table_name nvarchar(10)
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @table_name = N'test';
set @sql = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+@table_name;
execute sp_executesql @sql,N'@rowcount int output',@rowcount = @rowcount output; 
select @rowcount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable has to be declared in the appropriate context. try

```
declare @table_name varchar(50)

set @table_name ='users'
EXEC('declare @rcnt int;SELECT @rcnt = COUNT(*) FROM '+ @table_name+';select @rcnt ')
```